# Rc circuit tutorial question with unknown capacitor

Tags: circuit-analysis, phasor

An Rc circuit consists of a 4 ohm resistor in series with another resistor and a capacitor,both of unknown values..The source voltages and current in the circuit are respectively given by:

Vs bar=100 angle 0 degree V,1KHZ..I bar=5 angle O degree A

if the circuit has a leading power factor,and consumes a true power of 400W,calculate the values of the unknown resistor and capacitor..

the answer are R=12 ohm and C=13.3 micro Farad(F)..

My problem is how can i find the C=13.3 micro Farad(F)..i've already get the R=12 ohm for unknown resistor..pls help!!!...

Comment: "if the circuit has a leading power factor...". It couldn't actually be otherwise!

Comment: There has to be an error in what you say because current and applied voltage cannot be in phase (angle 0)

Answer (score 1):

If the circuit has a leading power factor (which makes sense) the current and voltage steady-state phasors cannot be in phase.  Are you sure that's the correct problem statement?

You can solve for the circuit's impedance Z_bar = V_bar / I_bar.  Since this is a series RC circuit, the impedance can be represented as Z_bar = R + 1/(jwC).  The left side is in polar coordinates and the right side in rectangular.  Convert the left side to rectangular coordinates (Re{Z} + jIm{Z}).  You'll then have 1/(jwC) = jIm{Z}.  Solve for C.

Comment: Can i use the XC^2=RC^2+XC^2?

Comment: Do you mean Z^2 = R^2 + Xc^2 ?  Where, Z is the magnitude of the total impedance and Xc = 1/(wC).

Comment: Ok Nathan,thanks bro but i've got a unknow resistor is 12 ohm i used a p=i^2.r formula..now my next question is Xc,if i get the xc very well,i've already know how to get a remaining of the unknown capacitor of C=13.3 micro Farad(F)..

Comment: my problem now is i don't know how can i solve this out and find the xc value before i find the unknown capacitor value..

Comment: It sounds like you know how to find R...  Then you can find the total impedance, Z = V/I.  Because this is an RC circuit, you know that the magnitude of the impedance is related to R and C by: Z^2 = R^2 + Xc^2.  So you know Z, you know R, you can solve or Xc.  Once you find Xc, you can use Xc = 1/wC to solve for C, where w = 2*pi*f.  Make sense?

Comment: ok nathan,i've got an idea for that,i'll write like this Z=V/I
=100 angle 0 degree/5 angle 0 degree i'll get an answer for Z impedance is 20 angle 0 degree..

Comment: Another one thing is Nathan,i finding Xc value,can i use a Z=R^2+Xc^2(i'll put the square root) over the R^2 + Xc^2 is that ok for it?

Comment: Since you want to solve for Xc, you want to rearrange for Xc:\begin{equation} X_c = \sqrt{Z^2 - R^2} \end{equation}

Comment: Nathan can i have a whole step of calculation for xc?